# Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range For Dimensional Array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to read and copy a data set from a spreadsheet into an array. However, I receive an error code titled "Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range" whenever I run my code.

The error seems to be at Line 15 but I'm not sure exactly what the error is and how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Sub ObtainData()
    ' Declare and initialize your variables. Turn off screen updating
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim data_arr(1 To 3, 1 To 100) As Variant
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer

    ' Obtain file name containing data from user
    FileName = InputBox("Enter File Name", "Hold up, wait a minute...", "19-03-04-MON JP")

    ' Open the file containing data using file name input from user
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\survey\" & FileName)

    ' Double-check if the right file is open. Output in Message Box.
    MsgBox "The Name of the Active Workbook is " & ActiveWorkbook.Name

    ' Copy data from file into an array
    For x = 1 To 3
        For y = 1 To 100
            data_arr(y, x) = Cells(y, x).Value
        Next y
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Your array is 3 x 100 but your loop is filling a 100 x 3 array so you need to swap the x and y. That said, you don't need a loop at all to fill an array from a range. `data_arr=cells(1,1).resize(3,100).value`.

Comment: The first dimension is `1 To 3`; `y=4` is out of bounds for `data_arr(y, x)`. Invert the subscripts - `data_arr(x, y) =`